# Why do multiples of 4 end with the last two digits being multiples of 4?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My reasoning is that the multiples of 4 are periodic about 20, and that they would be periodic about any multiple of 4 as well. We choose 100 because we don't need to perform any actual division and just need to extract the last two digits.

Similarly, the multiples of 8 require the last three digits to be a multiple of 8, 16 requires the last 4 digits.

In general, $2^{n}$ requires the last $n$ digits to be a multiple of it, so that the number is a multiple of it. This is easy to test as we can ignore the the remaining digits.
$2^{n}$ is periodic about $10n$, which divides $10^{n}$.
Is my reasoning correct ?

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/mathematicsnotebook/divisibilityrules/divisibility4/alternate-proof-using-modular-arithmetic

Answer (score 2):

The point is that you can always write a number $n$ as

$$
n = 100\cdot a+ b
$$
where $0\le b\le 99$ is the number corresponding to the last two digits.

Now, since $100 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$, this implies that

$$ n\equiv b \pmod 4$$

Thus $n$ is divisible by $4$ if and only if $b$ is divisible by 4.

You can replace $100$ with $10^k$ and $4$ with $2^k$ for any fixed $k\ge1$ you want and the argument will still hold.

Comment: Later on 1000 is divisible by 8 and 10000 by 16, which is why I made that extension. Is my proof rigorous enough?

Comment: @user230452 Yes, I think you mean the same. Maybe your terminology is not perfectly clear.